# Just last added element in database got parent in CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is the problem:
I've got a simple app that stores some data, I've got two ViewControllers:
CategoryViewController and ItemsViewController.

I’m trying to filter data to show items which belongs to a specific category. For example: Category "Buy" should have only "Apples","Oranges","Pears" items. But it shows only last added item.

```
func loadItems(with request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest(), predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) {

    let categoryPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentCategory.name MATCHES %@", (selectedCategory?.name)!)

    if let additionalPredicate = predicate {
        request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [categoryPredicate,
                                                                                additionalPredicate])
    } else {
        request.predicate = categoryPredicate
    }

    do {
        itemArray =  try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("error fetching data from context\(error)")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

So I've got 4 categories at the moment and here is what sqlite shows, just last added items got parent value

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I had relationship "toOne".Changed it "toMany" in DBName.xcdatamodeld and now everything works